$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac 1{\epsilon} \int_0 ^{\infty} f(x ,\epsilon) dx$
Check if the following limit exist and find the value if it exist .
$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}  \frac 1{\epsilon}\int_0 ^{\infty} e^{-x/{\epsilon} }(\cos (3x)+ x^2 +\sqrt{x+4} ) dx $
My Attempt :-
For $ X > 0 $
Let  $I( X ,\epsilon)$
$=   \int_0 ^X - \frac d{dx} (e^{-x/{\epsilon} })(\cos (3x)+ x^2 +\sqrt{x+4} ) dx $  .
Integrating by parts ,
$=-\big[  e^{-x/{\epsilon} }(\cos (3x)+ x^2 +\sqrt{x+4}) \big]_0 ^X  + \int_0 ^X 
 e^{-x/{\epsilon} } \big( -3\sin (3x) +2x + \frac 1{2\sqrt{x+4}} \big) dx $
$\big[ 3-  e^{-X/{\epsilon} }(\cos (3X)+ X^2 +\sqrt{X+4})\big]+\int_0 ^X 
 e^{-x/{\epsilon} } \big( -3\sin (3x) +2x + \frac 1{2\sqrt{x+4}} \big) dx $
Let $\epsilon >0$ , Then
$\lim_{X \rightarrow \infty} I(x ,\epsilon)=3+ \lim_{X \rightarrow \infty} 
  \int_0 ^X 
 e^{-x/{\epsilon} } \big( -3\sin (3x) +2x + \frac 1{2\sqrt{x+4}} \big) dx    $
Again $\int _0 ^X  e^{-x/{\epsilon} }2x dx
  $
$=-2\epsilon X e^{-X/{\epsilon} } +2{\epsilon}^2(1-e^{-X/{\epsilon} }) $
Taking $\lim_{X \rightarrow \infty}\int _0 ^X  e^{-x/{\epsilon} }2x dx=2{\epsilon}^2 $
Again $ \int e^{ax}\sin (bx)= \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2} (a\sin(bx) -b\cos(bx))$
So $ \int_0 ^X e^{-x/{\epsilon}}\sin (3x) =-\frac{\epsilon e^{-X/{\epsilon}}}{1+3{\epsilon}^2}(\sin (3X)+ 3\epsilon \cos(3X))+\frac{3{\epsilon}^2}{1+3{\epsilon}^2}  $
Taking limit as $X\rightarrow \infty$ , the above integral converges to $\frac{3{\epsilon}^2}{1+3{\epsilon}^2}  $
The middle integrand $\frac{e^{-x/{\epsilon}}}{\sqrt{x+4}}< \frac{e^{-x/{\epsilon}}}{2}  $
And so integrating and taking limit as $X\rightarrow \infty$ , we get
$\lim_{X\rightarrow \infty} \int_0 ^X \frac{e^{-x/{\epsilon}}}{\sqrt{x+4}} <\frac{\epsilon}2 $
Is there a problem with the above boundedness?
The above limits are all for $\epsilon >0$. How to tackle the limits $\epsilon <0$ ?
The answer is given $3$

where did you find this problem?

@Sine of the Time  PhD entrance exam question India

By integration by parts, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$
\begin{align}&\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x/\epsilon}\bigg(\cos (3x)+ x^2 +\sqrt{x+4}\bigg),dx\\&=-e^{-x/\epsilon}\bigg(\cos (3x)+ x^2 +\sqrt{x+4}\bigg)\bigg\vert_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x/\epsilon}\bigg(3\sin(3x)-2x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+4}}\bigg),dx\\
&=3+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x/\epsilon}\bigg(3\sin(3x)-2x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+4}}\bigg)\end{align}
Now $g_{\epsilon}(x):=e^{-x/\epsilon}\bigg(3\sin(3x)-2x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+4}}\bigg)$ are measurable and integrable functions such that $|g_{\epsilon}|$ is dominated by $(3+2x+\frac{1}{4})e^{-x}$.  It is an easy check that $\int_{0}^{\infty}   (3+2x+\frac{1}{4})e^{-x}\,dx<\infty$
and $g_{\epsilon}\xrightarrow{\epsilon\to 0}0$ almost everywhere. Thus the dominated convergence theorem gives you that:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x/\epsilon}\bigg(3\sin(3x)+2x+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+4}}\bigg)\xrightarrow{\epsilon\to 0} 0$$
which gives you the answer as $3$.
It does not make any sense to consider the cases for $\epsilon<0$ as the function itself becomes non-integrable.
